# How can I sort a specific column from a CSV file using C programming?

Tags: c, sorting, csv, bubble-sort, insertion-sort

Assuming that CSV file has very large data set on each column.I want to read from one specific column and sort (Bubble or insertion sort) them in descending order. I'm sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: Try Excel or other existing tool, including numerous 'scriptable languages'. This is a non-trivial (and not time efficient) operation to do in C unless there are specific requirements to do so. If the task is to *learn* C, then there are so many different concepts to learn about here. Simply correctly reading in the data is a chapter in a book.

Comment: You'll need (a) a representation of your CSV data in memory, code for reading your CSV file into that modeled representation, and (c) a sorting algorithm implementation tailored to sort that representation. Sounds like a challenging task. Have fun with it.

Comment: Well, the requirement is to use C programming, couldn't find anything similar online for C. I believe, I can also use C++/Java. @user2864740

Comment: @WhozCraig Tell me about it. It's only 1/4th of the problem.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how large is "very large".  And if it is indeed so large, what optimistic neanderthal suggested using bubble-sort or insertion-sort on it, *both* of which harbor a worst-case O(N^2) complexity?

Comment: 8726, to be exact. @WhozCraig

Comment: Read the entire file and split each line using comma as delimiter. Store the split results in a matrix. Then call [qsort](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm) function and define a compare function which will compare the records as you wish. The result will be rows sorted according to the condition specified in compare function. And 8726 is not a large data set! :-) Splitting can be done using [strtok](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) function.

Comment: Start by parsing your file, then you can find how to sort it, and store it properly